# How to include UITabBarController in UISplitViewController?

Tags: uitabbarcontroller, uisplitviewcontroller, ipad

Hello every one,
        I found [this](https://github.com/nfjinjing/human-rights-ios) universal app in github.Is their any sample iPad app related to link which have tab bar controller. I want to make a UISplitViewController in portrait mode just like in the Settings app with the UITabBarController. How can I do it? Please help me to overcome this problem. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, according to iOS guidelines a SplitViewController should be the root view controller of application. So legally you cannot add split View Controller on tabBarController. At least the view controller containing splitView controller must be on window OR must be root view controller

You will have to make tabBarController your root view controller and add a split view controller as one of the view controllers of tabBar. I have tried this successfully

Comment: In rootView of splitViewController, I added the UITabBarController instead of UINavigationViewController. Is it Legal.

Comment: This is what iOS View Programming Guide says
'A split view controller must always be the root of any interface you create. In other words, you must always install the view from a UISplitViewController object as the root view of your application’s window. The panes of your split view interface may then contain navigation controllers, tab bar controllers, or any other type of view controller you need to implement your interface. Split view controllers cannot be presented modally.'